# Kubernetes externalName service keep pending on dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-dashboard

I create a externalName service to aws RDS db, everything works just fine except Dashboard status always pending. How to fix the dashboard status, is there any annotation to resolve it ?

- Kubernetes 1.14
- Istio 1.4.2
- Dashboard v2.0.0-beta4+0.gf232c589
- AWS EKS.7

```
apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: postgres
     name: postgres
     namespace: staging
   spec:
     externalName: db-staging.xxxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
     type: ExternalName
     ports:
       - port: 5432
   status:
     loadBalancer: {}
```

Dashboard always show pending for externalName service

[image]

Comment: Could You provide more details? You talk about dashboard, but You provide posgres service, something is not right here i think? Could You check if you'r pods are in running state?

Comment: hi, i add an external postgres Service, everything work find, can see postgres service on Dashboard (image). the thing is, it always stuck at pending status (the pie icon on the left) and I want to ask is there a way to make it to success status (green checked icon)

Comment: Could You please check if your pods are running and provide logs to check why it's not working? Use `kubectl get pods,svc -o wide --all-namespaces` to show all pods and svc. Use `kubectl logs <name_of_pod>` to see logs

Comment: hi, it's a ExternalName service, so there is no pod.
this is `get svc` result
```NAME        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                        PORT(S)              AGE   SELECTOR
postgres    ExternalName   <none>           db-staging.xxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com   5432/TCP             25h   <none>```

Comment: I have Kubernetes 1.17.0 on baremetal and I have the same effect with this yaml. 

    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: externalname-stays-pending
    spec:
      externalName: niels.basjes.nl
      type: ExternalName
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 443
          targetPort: 443

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the dashboard so I reported it as such.
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/4736

My best guess at this point is that this is caused by the fact that this Service does not get a ClusterIP.

Update: This bug has been fixed in kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0-rc7 and later.